# Assign a sub class to an interface, with generics and covariant involved

Tags: c#, .net, covariance, contravariance

I defined 3 interfaces:

```
public interface IManufacturerInput
{
}
public interface IManufacturerOutput
{
}
public interface IManufacturerApi<in S, out T>
    where S : IManufacturerInput
    where T : IManufacturerOutput
{
    T Calculate(S);
}
```

And I defined a specific Manufacturer:

```
public class ManufacturerAInput : IManufacturerInput
{
}
public class ManufacturerAOutput : IManufacturerOutput
{
}
public class ManufacturerAApi : IManufacturerApi<ManufacturerAInput, ManufacturerAOutput>
{
     public ManufacturerAOutput Calculate(ManufacturerAInput)
     {
         return null;
     }
}
```

And In Main() I created a ManufacturerAApi, and try assign it to IManufacturerApi.

```
IManufacturerApi<IManufacturerInput, IManufacturerOutput> api = new ManufacturerAApi();
```

But it failed. The error message said (just abstract meaning):

```
Can't convert from ManufacturerAApi to IManufacturerApi<IManufacturerInput, IManufacturerOutput>
```

So is there any way I can make the assignment work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because `IManufacturerApi<IManufacturerInput, IManufacturerOutput>` and `IManufacturerApi<ManufacturerAInput, ManufacturerAOutput>` are not the same. I know, generics are really not dynamic types :( but instead you create a class each time you specify it's parameters

Comment: `S` is contravariant in `IManufacturerApi<S, T>` so for this to work `IManufacturerInput` would need to be a subtype of `ManufacturerAInput` instead of a supertype.

Comment: What are you happy to change? Obviously if you changed it to `IManufacturerApi<ManufacturerAInput, ManufacturerAOutput> api = new ManufacturerAApi();` then it would work but are you happy to change this? What exactly are your requirements? Or indeed you could get the assignment to "work" by just using `var api = ...` but I assume this is not what you are after?

Comment: @Emad  Thank you. So maybe there is no way to program to interface, I guess. (I searched a lot but found no way)

Comment: @Lee Thanks. But I want a base Input class, and all other specific Input class derive from it.

Comment: @Chris  I just want to program to interface. For example I create an ManufacturerBApi later, I want asssign api with instance of ManufacturerAApi or ManufacturerBApi. If user clicks Manufactuer A, I assign it to A. If user clicks B, assign it Manufacturer B.

Comment: Thanks @Chris . Now I removed the generics <in S> , and use IManufacturerInput in place of S, and cast it to MannufacturerAInput in manufacturer A's class . Then, it works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are proposing isn't type safe. Let's change the names of your types to make the issue clearer:

```
public interface IPetFood { }
public interface IPetSound { }

public interface IPetCage<in S, out T>
    where S : IPetFood
    where T : IPetSound
{
    T Feed(S s);
}

public class DogFood : IPetFood { }
public class CatFood : IPetFood { }
public class Bark : IPetSound { }

public class DogCage : IPetCage<DogFood, Bark>
{
    public Bark Feed(DogFood input)
    {
        return new Bark();
    }
}
```

And now suppose this is legal:

```
IPetCage<IPetFood, IPetSound> api = new DogCage();
```

Then we could do the following:

```
api.Feed(new CatFood()); //oops we've just given the dog some catfood.
```

The assignment will not work because `S` is contravariant, which means that any possible `IPetFood` passed into `api.Feed` would need to be a subtype of `DogFood` and you have the opposite; `IPetFood` is a superset of `DogFood`.

Comment: Thanks. That's imperssive. Finally I deleted <in S>, and replace it with IManufacturerInput, and cast it to ManufacturerAInput in manufacturer A. Then it work now.

Comment: Yes, C# is really strong typed, and also ensures type safe in generics. So I use type cast to get around this.